# Update query comparing two tables - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I am trying to change the sign of amount field in tdataseg table when the account_type in aif_hyp_acct_type table is ' ','R','L','Q'. aif_hyp_acct_type is the master table. It has loadid, account and account_type fields. tdataseg table has account, amount and many other fields.

I tried this query and get **ORA-01427** error.

> Single row subquery returns more than one row.

```
update tdataseg
set tdataseg.amount = 
    (select decode(sign(tdataseg.amount),-1,abs(tdataseg.amount),1,-abs(tdataseg.amount),0) 
     from tdataseg, aif_hyp_acct_type 
     where tdataseg.loadid = aif_hyp_acct_type.loadid 
           and tdataseg.account = aif_hyp_acct_type.account 
           and aif_hyp_acct_type.account_type in (' ','R','L','Q'))
```

Comment: The error says that your `SELECT` sub-query returns more than 1 row.  Run it on its own and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the problem is that you think you have a correlated subquery, but you don't.  The outer table is mentioned in the inner query.  You need to remove that reference:

```
update tdataseg
    set tdataseg.amount = (select decode(sign(tdataseg.amount), -1, abs(tdataseg.amount),
                                         1,-abs(tdataseg.amount), 0) 
                           from aif_hyp_acct_type 
                           where tdataseg.loadid = aif_hyp_acct_type.loadid and
                                 tdataseg.account = aif_hyp_acct_type.account and
                                 aif_hyp_acct_type.account_type in (' ','R','L','Q')
                          );
```

EDIT:

You would get that error if there were no matches and the column were declared `not null`.  Here is one fix:

```
update tdataseg
    set tdataseg.amount = (select coalesce(max(decode(sign(tdataseg.amount), -1, abs(tdataseg.amount),
                                                      1,-abs(tdataseg.amount), 0)), 0)
                           from aif_hyp_acct_type 
                           where tdataseg.loadid = aif_hyp_acct_type.loadid and
                                 tdataseg.account = aif_hyp_acct_type.account and
                                 aif_hyp_acct_type.account_type in (' ','R','L','Q')
                          );
```

That will set non-matches to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. But I get the error "ORA 01407 cannot update tdataseg.amount to null.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to solve such update problems with a `MERGE` statement. I find it a bit more natural to write.

```
MERGE INTO tdataseg 
USING (
       SELECT loadid, account 
         FROM aif_hyp_acct_type 
        WHERE account_type IN (' ','R','L','Q')
      ) q
   ON (tdataseg.loadid=q.loadid AND tdataseg.account=q.account)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET amount = - ABS(amount);
```

You put the table you want to change after the `MERGE INTO`. The master table is subsetted in the `USING` query. The join condition goes into the `ON` clause, and the actual data change is specified after `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET`.